# Nonhomogeneous Neumann Boundary Conditions for the 3D Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, 3d, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I have recently came accross an interesting boundary problem regarding the temperature content inside a cake in an oven. The solution assumes the boundary conditions to be fixed at the oven temperature and imposes homogeneous Dirichlet conditions by [substracting the oven temperature from all temperatures in the cake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO2YM.png). However, I don't think fixed boundary conditions would be physically accurate. Is there a way to define the boundary conditions so that it shows the outside layer of the cake changes temperature over time as the cake can't just be at the oven temperature. This seems to result in a nonhomogeneous Neumann boundary condition problem. Since nonhomogeneous conditions are a bit harder to solve, especially in 3D, is there a way of using a similar method as in the image I linked? Would substracting the oven temperature from the boundary conditions as well not imply insulated cake surfaces which would mean that the outside of the cake does not undergo any change whatsoever? I would really appreciate it if you helped me understand how I should approach the issue.

Comment: For a one dimensional heat equation, it would be $u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=T_o$ where $T_o$ is the oven tempereature.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment:*

A more realistic boundary condition for this problem is
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=-\alpha(u-T_0)\,\,\text{on}\,\,\partial\Omega, \tag{1}
$$
where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ is the outward normal derivative of $u$ at the boundary $\partial\Omega$ of the region $\Omega$, and $\alpha$ is a positive constant. Repeating with this BC the calculation I did in my previous comment, it's possible to show that the average temperature of the body decreases over time if its surface temperature is higher than the ambient temperature $T_0$, and increases in the opposite case. Also, it's possible to transform $(1)$ into a homogeneous BC by subtracting $T_0$ from $u$.

(A remark: $(1)$ is known as Robin boundary condition.)

Answer (score 0):

The heat-flow boundary conditions that you have suggested
$$\partial_xu(t,0)=\partial_xu(t,L)=T_{\text{oven}}$$
Are wrong, for two reasons:

First, the dimensions are wrong. The LHS has dimensions of temperature/length, but the RHS has dimensions of temperature.

Second, these boundary conditions mean that the cake is heated from one side and cooled from the other side at an equal rate, meaning that it won't cook at all (as shown by Goncalo). This is because you forgot to take into account the orientation of the normal vectors.

The rate at which heat **leaves** the cake is given by $\boldsymbol n\cdot \nabla u$, where $\boldsymbol n$ is the unit **outward** normal to the cake's surface. Conversely, the rate at which heat **enters** the cake is given by $-\boldsymbol n\cdot \nabla u$. In one dimension, this unit outward normal is simply the number $+1$ on the right side of the cake and $-1$ on the left side.  So, given our heat flow rate $\gamma$ , your BCs should be

$$-(+1)\cdot\partial_xu(t,L)=\gamma~~~(\text{right side}) \\ -(-1)\cdot \partial_x u(t,0)=\gamma~~~(\text{left side})$$

I.e
$$\partial_x u(t,0)=-\gamma \\ \partial_xu(t,L)=\gamma$$

Comment: Okay that clears my misconceptions about Neumann BCs. I thought the conditions could be equal to a temperature just as in Dirichlet conditions but they would be a derivative instead, which does not make any sense. Then I guess I can't turn these nonhomogenous conditions to homogenous as I referred earlier? How do I solve the problem in this form? And would it be realistic for the heat flow rate to be the same for all the boundary conditions, since I am working in 3D?

Comment: 1: No, you can't homogenize these Neumann BCs. That would imply that there is no heat flow (clearly wrong). 
2: Using standard methods, i.e separation of variables.
3: No, it probably isn't "realistic", but models always need to have some simplifying assumptions.

Comment: Would separation of variables be enough to solve it? I found an [article](https://www.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/ttu/f08/m4354_f08/m4354_ch6_non_homo_prob.pdf) that solves the nonhomogeneous Neumann BCs although I have trouble following it as it seems to skip a few steps. Do you know any source that could help me?

Comment: @Orkiel Please tell me which specific steps you are struggling to connect and I can fill in the gaps for you.